# How can I align the inside of a Text view?

Tags: swiftui, text, alignment

I have a multiline text field which I would *like* to appear as:

[image]

I’ve tried every combination of `padding` and `frame` that I can find on the Internet, and I get something like this:

```swift
Text("the cat sat on the mat\nand that is that")
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
    .padding(.vertical, 6.0)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .border(.black)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

If the text is longer, it will move over to the left, but I can’t get it there from the beginning.

What’s the technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another border helps illustrate what's happening:

```
Text("the cat sat on the mat\nand that is that")
   .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
   .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
   .padding(.vertical, 6.0)
   .border(Color.green)
   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
   .border(.black)
```

[image]

So, you can see that the `Text` doesn't take up the entire `frame`. You can add an alignment to the frame so that the `Text` appears where you intend.

```
Text("the cat sat on the mat\nand that is that")
   .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
   .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
   .padding(.vertical, 6.0)
   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // <-- Here
   .border(.black)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that’s it. I don’t think I ever tried both the dimensions and the alignment in the `frame`.